# NameError: name 'countrychoice' is not defined

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nameerror, defined

I'm having some trouble with the current program I'm writing.

I'm letting the user type in a country, and then a city city in that country, and then see a weather forecast for the choosen city using API.

I'm using a class, like this:

```
class requestChoice:

    def __init__(self):
        self.countrychoice = None
        self.citychoice = None

    def countryChoice(self):
        self.countrychoice = input("Enter which country your city is in(in english): ")

    def cityChoice(self):
        self.citychoice = input("Enter the name of the city: ")
```

And my main program looks like this:

```
from requestchoice import requestChoice

import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Introducion"""
    print ("\nThis program lets you see a weather forecast for your choosen city.")

rc = requestChoice()
while True:
    print("\nWhen you have typed in country and city, press 3 in the menu to see the weather forecast for your choice.\n")
    menu = input("\nPress 1 for contry\nPress 2 for city\nPress 3 to see forecast\nPress 4 to exit\n")
    if menu == "1":
        rc.countryChoice()
    elif menu == "2":
        rc.cityChoice()
    elif menu == "3":
        r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/forecast/q/" + countrychoice + "/" + citychoice + ".json")
        data = r.json()
        try:
            for day in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
                print (day['date']['weekday'] + ":")
                print ("Conditions: ", day['conditions'])
                print ("High: ", day['high']['celsius'] + "C", '\n' "Low: ", day['low']['celsius'] + "C", '\n')
        except Exception as e:
            print ("\nHave you typed in the correct country and city?\nBecause we got a" ,e, "error")
    else: 
        print ("\nGoodbye")
        break
```

When I run my program I get the error `NameError: name 'countrychoice' is not defined`. It is going to be the same error with the `citychoice`. I've tried creating a list in my class and append the `countrychoice` to the list but without any luck. How am I supposed to make it work as wished?

Comment: Can you past the **exact** traceback please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `NameError` on here:

```
r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/forecast/q/" + countrychoice + "/" + citychoice + ".json")
```

because you have no names `countrychoice` and `citychoice` defined. Perhaps you meant to use `rc.countrychoice` and `rc.citychoice` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You have to access them with the corresponding object name. In this case

```
rc.countrychoice
rc.citychoice
```

So, this line

```
r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/forecast/q/" + countrychoice + "/" + citychoice + ".json")
```

becomes

```
r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/forecast/q/" + rc.countrychoice + "/" + rc.citychoice + ".json")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `rc.countrychoice` and `rc.citychoice` here

```
    r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/forecast/q/" + rc.countrychoice + "/" + rc.citychoice + ".json")
```